# How to scale down Highcharts chart to 50% of its original size without manually changing fonts for axis and title?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, charts, highcharts

Is there a way to show minimized copy of the Highcharts chart without manually adjusting fonts?
It should look like taking a screenshot and just resizing it to 50% of original size.
Maybe there is some library that I'm not aware of. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a modified Highcharts?

Comment: Css can't help you? There are scale properties.

Comment: you already mentioned the right way, export it to a picture and then set with the reduced width.

Answer (score 1):

Use export module to achieve that.

You will find more information in the following doc: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

**Export module:**

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

**Example chart config:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }],
    
    exporting:{
    scale:0.5
    }
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v6rpzyqf/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.scale